# [UWP]launch mobile aplications in uwp C#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I found some new APIs in Windows 10 Mobile device portal that allows to run applications on user phone . 
you can launch this like to see the result : http://{PhoneIP}/api/app/packagemanager/packages
and there's another API to launch applications : 
api/taskmanager/app

Starts a modern app

HTTP verb: POST

Parameters

appid : PRAID of app to start, hex64 encoded

### package : Full name of the app package, hex64 encoded

I have this code to run applications but doesn't work any idea ?

```
public class PackageInfoToRun
{
    public string appid { get; set; }
    public string package { get; set; }
    public string PackageFamilyName { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneInstalledPackages
    {
        public Installedpackage[] InstalledPackages { get; set; }
    }

    public class Installedpackage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PackageFamilyName { get; set; }
        public string PackageFullName { get; set; }
        public int PackageOrigin { get; set; }
        public string PackageRelativeId { get; set; }
        public bool IsXAP { get; set; }
    }

private static string Encode(string strn)
    {
        var toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strn);
        string appName64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
        appName64 = appName64.Replace(" ", "20%");
        return appName64;
    }

public async Task<PhoneInstalledPackages> GetInstalledApps()
    {
        //  /api/app/packagemanager/packages
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1/api/app/packagemanager/packages");
        string res = "";
        webrequest.Method = "GET";
        try
        {
            using (var webresponse = await webrequest.GetResponseAsync())
            using (StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                res = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
            var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PhoneInstalledPackages>(res);
            return des;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

public async Task<bool> RunAppAsync(string appid, string packagename)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage http = new HttpResponseMessage();
        string str;
        try
        {
            var package = new PackageInfoToRun()
            {
                appid = Encode(appid),
                package = Encode(packagename)
            };
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var serial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(package);
                http = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1/api/taskmanager/app", new StringContent(serial, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = http)
                {
                    str = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    string retur = str;
                    if (retur.Contains("true"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

what's going wrong in my codes ? thanks :)

Comment: Which part of your code isn't working?

Comment: public async Task<bool> RunAppAsync(string appid, string packagename)
can't run application and go to search in store !

Comment: Is an exception thrown?

Comment: no there's no exception the response message is : "{\"Reason\" : \"Missing app id or package name argument.\"}"

Comment: One problem would be that you're using `base64` encoding when the API requires you to use `hex64` encoding. Can you provide a link to the API reference?

Comment: if you are using windows 10 mobile you can enable your device portal on phone (settings -> update & security -> for developers) if you navigate to the device ip (it shows under device portal an you access it on phone with http://127.0.0.1) at top right side of the page there's a help . there you can find API reference

Comment: still my problem didn't solved , anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I used your code with small changes and it works for me.
now RunAppAsync looks like this. Don't forget to specify a *PORT*.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();           
var serial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(package);
var result = await client.PostAsync(String.Format("http://127.0.0.1:*PORT*/api/taskmanager/app?appid={0}&package={1}", package.appid, package.package), new StringContent(serial));
```

Where the package is

```
var package = new PackageInfoToRun()          
{
    appid = Encode(app.PackageRelativeId),
    package = Encode(app.PackageFullName),
};
```

And the app variable is an instance of InstalledPackage class.